# Optimize BLF-reader for Python CAN performance

Tags: python, performance, can-bus, python-can

I have a big blf file, `blf_file.blf`, and an associated dbc file, `dbc_file.dbc`. I need to read and decode all the messages and store them in a list. For this I use the [python-can](https://github.com/hardbyte/python-can) library:

```py
decoded_mess = []

db = cantools.db.load_file('dbc_file.dbc')

with can.BLFReader('blf_file.blf') as can_log:
  for msg in can_log:
    decoded_mess.append(
      db.decode_message(msg.arbitration_id, msg.data)
      )
```

However, for my blf files (> 100 MB), this takes up to 5 minutes.

Is there a way to speed this up? In the end, I want to store every signal in a seperate list, so list comprehension is not an option.

Comment: I don't think you can speed the reading part up. Yet you can start your processing while reading if you don't need the list to full before starting.